# Kubernetes pod can't make web socket connection

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, kubernetes-ingress

I'm having a bit of an issue with setting up Kubernets for my situation. I'm making a game which has matchmaking. The matchmaking server will contact a game server to create a match ( via a web socket connection ) then return which server the game is on to the clients so they may connect to it.

The issue is that the match making pod does not want to connect to the game server pod. I'm using the Java web socket framework ( https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket ) and all I get as an error message when I try and connect is: "closed with exit code -1 additional info:" but there is no additional info. If I try using netty to make the websocket connection, I get a connection reset error. I'm almost positive the issue is with the matchmaking server and not the game server, because If I run the matchmaking server on my local computer, it happily talks with the game server and works correctly.

This is how the system is set up:

I have a cname record for the game server (E.X.): match.test.com

When a match is found it tries to make a web socket connection with the following url: "wss://match.test.com/socket"

I have an ingress record in kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: lang-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - matchmaking.test.com
      - match.test.com
    secretName: lang-tls-production
  rules:
    - host: matchmaking.test.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: admin-backend-service
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: match.languageattack.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: game-backend-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

and my service for the matchmaking:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: admin-backend-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8753
  selector:
    app: backend-admin
```

I really can't figure out why it specifically doesn't work from the kubernetes pod. the same pod has no issue making database or redis requests, so I'm not sure why it struggles specifically to make a websocket connection request

I have tried changing the sockets that are mapped and removing ssl encryption but neither has worked